# What happens if the return type of the remote method is unknown in the local JVM?

Tags: java, rmi

Hi i have a quick question

What happens if the return type of the remote method is unknown in the local JVM?

Thanks

Comment: How can it be unknown? You are calling through an interface, and the interface has to specify the return type.

Comment: Thanks ,its not the answer that i was looking for but i figured out the answer from what you said , cheers

Comment: It's an answer to the question you asked. If it's not the answer you were looking for, the fault is in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As the programmer,you should be aware of the return type of the remote method.If you are simply calling that particular method,everything will be fine and JVM wouldn't interfere.
Now,this is not the same when you want to store the returned value in a variable.If the return type doesn't match with the recieving variable type,you will get an error.JVM will throw an error.
So you are the one who should be aware of the return type.

JVM is not remote.If you are running a java program,you should be having a JVM installed. The double value you are recieving cannot be stored in the integer type.

```
int r=value();
```

and

```
public double value()
```

`value()` is of the type double.This won't work,you will see an error at your end not at the remote end.

Comment: Thank you but that answer doesnt make any sense in my case  , I'm using  stubs and all that other related technology

Comment: Why don't you mention all that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error trying to load your client program, probably a NoSuchMethodException or NoClassDefFoundError, if the result type itself is unknown to the client JVM; or an UnmarshalException trying to deserialize the result if it *extends* the result type with a class unknown to the client JVM.

Answer (score -3):

the answer is the String or what ever  the  return type i have called in the interface throws a remote exception.

Comment: Are you looking for handling of RemoteException?

Comment: This is beacause,the types don't match!

Comment: Why don't you convert the retuurned value to a string and store it in a string variable?..`String getIt=remotefunction().toString();`This may not throw an error.Print `getIt` and analyse the output type.

Comment: I asked a simple question , I wanted to know what would happen i didn't ask for code

Comment: @JohnSmith Don't have a bad attitude. He is trying to help you.

Comment: This answer is nonsense. `String` doesn't throw remote exceptions.